# Confusion in usage of "of" in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, american-english, phrase-usage, parts-of-speech

I read the below statement today.

> "Muhammad Ali was born in the small town of Louisville." 
>   Here Louisville is described as a small town.

Normally when we use "small town of XXX", are we decribing

1. XXX as a small town, or
2. a small town inside something bigger called XXX(Let's say, a country)

Can someone please explain how does one interpret such statements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Louisville is a city in the state of Kentucky in the United States. I’m surprised your source would leave out the state, unless the publication was local, like a Louisville newspaper.

Comment: I read it in a book. It only mentioned the city/town. Can you please explain how to decide on which explanation to use?

Comment: Both your explanations are okay, and they’re the same, aren’t they? I think all small towns are part of larger entities, from counties to states to countries.

Comment: I am not sure if I conveyed my exact question. Apologies if I am not clear. I don't think they are the same. "small town of Louisville" refers to "Louisville" while "small town of USA" refers to some town IN "USA", not "USA" itself.

Comment: Then it would be your first case—“small town of Louisville” means a small town named Louisville.  A small town *in* the USA would be used if you don’t name the town.

Comment: But we can also talk about “the cities of Europe,” referring to Paris, Prague, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got confused.

Comment: Good question. However, this is better asked on [ell.se]. Voting to migrate.

Comment: It doesn't assert anything other than that Louisville is a small town.

Comment: @BillJ Please review my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note the definite article in "**the** small town of Louisville." While "XXX is **a** small town of …" has the indefinite article.

Both are valid, each with its distinctive meaning.

In the context, it means "the small town **called** Louisville".

HTH.

Comment: Thanks... It answered my question.

Comment: This is sense #11 of the preposition definitions at https://www.thefreedictionary.com/of